# Passing array from one component to another through parent component, but it doesn't work on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an array that I need to pass from one component to another through parent component.

Parent:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

<Component1 setArrFunction={setArr}/>

<Component2 myArr={arr}
```

Component1:(array comes form this component)

```
Component_1({setArrFunction })

useEffect(() => {
    setArrFunction(elRefs);
  }, [elRefs]);
```

elRefs is my array than contains refs of elements that I need, but it's not the problem here

Component2

```
Component_2({ myArr })

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunc);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', myFunc);
    };
  }, []);
```

And in component_2 I have this function that is ran on scroll and it runs forEach for my array. The problem is that on the first render this array is empty, and this happens when I console log my array in Component_2

```
[]
[]
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So my array is technically empty and my forEach doesn't work. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: But yes, since you're providing an empty array to the components initially, they're going to see an empty array initially (e.g., on first render). If you don't want them to see an empty array initially, don't create those components until you have a non-empty array. But an example might make it possible to provide a more useful answer.

Comment: The answer below works, I messed up with useEffect, but thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `useEffect` component will run after the render method has been done in `component1` at the same time the `component2` is rendered and its `useEffect` is called with `myArr which has empty value` and at this moment you attached `eventListener` with `emptyValue`. after a few moments `myArr` has been set but you're not using it anymore.

That was the reason, The solution is you need to add `myArr` to `useEffect` dependency and check for its value like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (myArr.length) {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunc);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", myFunc);
    };
  }
}, [myArr]);
```

Comment: Ok, this works, thank you, you are genius :D

Comment: @Filippo854 you're welcome, if the answer was helpful try to accept the answer

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah my bad, I fixed that, thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my problem wasn't that I got error or something, the function just didn't correctly run, because my array was empty and I needed it to have my elements